# IE8 - Form within a hidden div, return key no longer works

Tags: javascript, css, forms, internet-explorer-8

I have a login form that resides within a div with display: none; I then fade in the form using jquery but the Enter/Return key no longer submits the form. If I change the display to block, it works fine. This problem is IE only.

Any ideas?

Here's an example code that doesn't work;

```
<div id='formdiv' style='display: none;'>
<form id='loginForm' name='createLoginForm' method='post' action='' >
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' />
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='login_submit'  />
</form>
</div>
```

And I stuck this in the  to test the hiding/showing;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
setTimeout('$("#formdiv").show()',1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying when you hit return instead of clicking the submit button the form doesn't submit? 

What scripting are you using to processes the form data, could you post this code and your form code please. I think I have seen this issue before.

Comment: Cheers Joel, you must have some server side code to check your login credentials? Can I see this too?

Comment: Nope, with that code alone (with doctype and <head>) the form doesn't submit. It's nothing to do with PHP, literally just the HTML form.

Comment: Ok, the reason I ask to see some server side code is because some developer check if a form has been submitted by using `isset($_POST['submit']);`, the problem is IE doesn't send the submit button variable. If you're trying to say when you hit return it doesn't even load another page then my fix would be of no use :-)

Comment: What happens if you hide the form from script directly after the form element, rather than doing it in the HTML? Does that make a difference? (It's probably a good idea anyway, for no-JS fallback purposes.)

Comment: Why do you need to put the form into a div when you can show/hide on the form directly.  A form is a block level container, so that just sounds redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Since the problem seems relevant to whether the element *appears* on the page or not, you can still have it appear, but "cloak" it using a 1x1 wrapper div with overflow: hidden;

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .submit-wrapper
  {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
</style>

<div class="submit-wrapper">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
```

Comment: I used a modified version of this. I just "pushed" the button off screen. `#hiddenSubmit { position:absolute; top:-9999px; }`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's causing the problem, but refreshing the div's html after it's shown seems to fix the form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formdiv').show(500, function(){
        $('#formdiv').html($('#formdiv').html());
    });
});
```

Definitely not ideal, but since it seems to be an actual IE8 or jQuery bug, you may have to resort to a hack like this (maybe with a browser check around it).

Comment: Aye, I actually ended up putting a keypress event on the form, and submitting the form if it was the return key. Again, not ideal, but seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been bitten by this before. Basically, if the form was hidden when the page is rendered, then return-submit won't work for that form.

Here's a work around: 
http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter